# Adding newline to PHP string

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add new line at the end of string, so I could better see `<option>` in new lines, hovewer I get string with "\r\n" as text instead of new lines. What is wrong with code ?

```
foreach ($xml['ROW'] as $ar) {
   $tekstas = $ar['zz'] . ' (' . $ar['xx'] . ')';
   $insert .= '<option value="' . $ar['Adresas'] . '">' . $tekstas .'</option> "\r\n"' ;
}
echo nl2br(htmlentities($insert));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there, look at the right way to concatenate the new line to the rest of the string you generate.

```
foreach ($xml['ROW'] as $ar) {
 $tekstas = $ar['zz'] . ' (' . $ar['xx'] . ')';
 $insert .= '<option value="' . $ar['Adresas'] . '">' . $tekstas   .'</option> ' . PHP_EOL ;
}
echo nl2br(htmlentities($insert));
```

Comment: `\r\n` is used on Windows and `\n` on UNIX based systems. if you use the constant `PHP_EOL`, it will be more compatible on both.

Answer (score 2):

`'`-quoted strings do not honor escaped metacharacters like `"`-quoted ones do:

```
echo '\r' - outputs a literal backslash and an 'r'
echo "\r" - outputs a carriage return
```

the only escapes that are supported in `'` strings are `\'` and `\\`.

So..

```
'</option> "\r\n"' 
^---open single quote string
                 ^---close single-quote string
```

when it should be

```
'</option> ' . "\r\n"
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

"\r\n" should be in double quotes.

```
foreach ($xml['ROW'] as $ar) {
   $tekstas = $ar['zz'] . ' (' . $ar['xx'] . ')';
   $insert .= '<option value="' . $ar['Adresas'] . '">' . $tekstas .'</option>'."\r\n";
}
echo nl2br(htmlentities($insert));
```